# using smooth-scroll plugin on a button

Tags: javascript, html, smooth-scrolling

I'm using the Smooth-Scroll plugin from the following git - [link](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll).

It works great in places like navbar where I used it as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#initial">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#end">end</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script>
    var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]');
</script>
```

However, on the same screen, I have a search button inside a form and I had liked it to act as the navbar - I want that once the user clicks on the search button it will smooth-scroll to the next section.

My form looks like this and I tried the following:

```
<form method="POST" class="hiscore_query">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
    <button type="submit" href="#skills"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

and I tried to change my js into:

```
<script>
    var scroll = new SmoothScroll('button[href*="#"]');
</script>
```

but nothing happens.

Is there any way to make that search button do that smooth scroll?

Thank you

Comment: The library you used is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button>`s can't be used as links. Change `<button type="submit" href="#skills"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>` to `<a href="#skills"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>`.

Comment: But I need a button...Do you suggest I edit the style of "I" to look like a button?

Comment: Use this html then `<a href="#skills"><button><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></a>`

Comment: Thank you mate!

Comment: Make sure to mark as the answer